# IntelliJ IDEA underlines my Scala code with implicits, but code works

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, spray

This is full code:

```
   package com.example.controller

import spray.routing.{HttpService, Route}
import spray.http.StatusCodes

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait RentController extends HttpService{

  var books: List[String] = List("1","2","3","4")

  def rentBook(intNum: Int): Future[Unit] = Future[Unit] {
    val book = books.find(p => p.equals(intNum.toString))
    if(book.head.equals("4")) throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
  }

  def giveBackBook(intNum: Int): String = {
    val book = books.find(p => p.equals(intNum.toString))
    book.head
  }

  val rent: Route =
    pathPrefix("rent") {
      path("book" / IntNumber) { intNum =>
        get {
          onComplete(rentBook(intNum)) {
            case Success(_) => complete(StatusCodes.OK)
            case Failure(_) => complete(StatusCodes.Accepted)
          }
        }
      }
    }

  val giveBack: Route =
    pathPrefix("giveBack") {
      path("book" / IntNumber) { intNum =>
        get {
          onSuccess(Future.successful(giveBackBook(intNum))) {
            extraction: String => complete(extraction)
          }
        }
      }
    }

}
```

What is weird, He only underlines OnSuccess, but OnComplete is apparently correct for him. Code works, but i'm wondering if i maybe made some mistake somewhere. So please tell if i'm missing some imports, or it's just IntelliJ bug.

## Edit

I changed code, right now functions rendBook and giveBackBook arent logically correct, and don't do much, but you should reproduce it easily

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Copy pasting this will not work for anyone.

Comment: [Bug report is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL) with a sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If you look closely this is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example :) Two routes, one works, one no, all Imports :) Every piece of this code is needed to verify my problem i think :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder I know, but i want to have expertise from some Scala Specialist, if i didn't make any mistake :)

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk How exactly will `import com.example.repository.BookRepository` compile for me?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OK, i get it, sorry :)

Comment: @KamilBanaszczyk No need to be sorry :), Just add all the necessary types for us to try and reproduce this locally.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i updated my code

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11117) in IntelliJ's Scala plugin - excessive use of implicits might get you there. If you know about magnet pattern - which is also what [Spray uses](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/), it requires a lot of implicit conversions to overcome some overloading limitations in Scala.

I had this problem when I've used the magnet pattern to implement some features, so not only using Spray - some of the code was underlined, while the rest of it no, but it worked anyway.